# what SF features are subject to regulation?

Tags: force.com

I recently learned that Chatter was a SF feature that was subject to FINRA regulations.  Are there are other features of the platform that are/were subject to regulation? I understand that the regulation varies among industry, location, and level of govt, but if there are some features that stand out, I'd appreciate some help.

The reason why I'm asking this, is a developer what features should I be aware of as thorny, before pitching them as solutions for our user base.

Comment: i know posting SSNs on SF is a compliance no no, also...

Comment: I would suggest starting a community wiki answer for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Compliance Documents](http://www.salesforce.com/company/legal/compliance.jsp)

The above link provides a list of documents for the current Salesforce features that comply with some regulation somewhere (there's a number of them). Also read the Code of Conduct document for additional information. Note that they are also 508 Compliant (accessibility features required by the United States of America government in order for a product to be used by the government).

The information on 508 compliance is located on the pages:
[Accessibility Overview](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=accessibility_overview.htm&siteLang=en_US), [Enabling Accessiblity Mode](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=accessibility_enabling.htm&language=en_US), and probably for developers, the most important being: [Accessibility Recommendations for Specific User Groups](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=accessibility_recommendations.htm&language=en_US).

They're also subject to various regulations internationally, such as the Data Protection Directive (and its successors).